# Beautifulsoup span attribute has no value, find returns "None" how do I get the text?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Html:

```html
<h2 class="members-results" data-members-result="">
#           <span data-members-count="">78430</span> results based on your <span>search options</span>        </h2>
```

I need the value `78430`.

1st attempt:

```py
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
baitres = soup_page.find("span", attrs={'data-members-count'})
print(baitres)
```

Output: `None`.

2nd attempt:

```py
baitres = soup_page.find("span", attrs={'data-members-count'}).text
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Why doesn't this select the number as text?
And how should I have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was almost correct!

`Attrs` is a dictionary. The code is missing the value to match on. Normally you match on string (*or string empty*). However if all you want to do is match on attribute existing, then pass `True`. e.g: `baitres = soup_page.find("span", attrs={'data-members-count': True})`

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<h2 class="members-results" data-members-result=""><span data-members-count="">78430</span> results based on your <span>search options</span></h2>'
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
baitres = soup_page.find("span", attrs={'data-members-count': True})
print(baitres.text)
```